# Anderstand how to initialize the keycloak-angular service ? (bearerExcludedUrls, etc...)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using Angular 8.0.3, keycloak 8.0.0 and the [keycloak-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) 7.0.1

**Problem**

I managed to configure the authentication from my angular app. So every time that I go on my application without authorization header, I'm being redirected towards the keycloak login page.

If I want an unlogged person to access a public page (e. g.'/public/cities') without redirecting to the keycloak login page, should I use'bearerExcludedUrIs'? If so, what should I wear? If not, how to proceed?

from a more general point of view, the keycloak initialization function in the service provided has an initOption part. I don't exactly understand the meaning of all its attributes (onLoad, token, refreshToken, idToken, timeSkew, sheckLoginIframe, checkLoginIframeInterval, responseMode, flow). If an enlightened person willing to share his knowledge with me could enlighten me, I would be grateful...

**My code**

I'm using ngDoBootstrap to bootstrap the library and configure keycloak-angular. In this example, I tried to allow all the urls with the regex /.*/ (but nothing change).

```
const keycloakService = new KeycloakService();

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    PagesModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: KeycloakService,
      useValue: keycloakService,
    }
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  async ngDoBootstrap(app) {
    const { keycloakConfig } = environment;

    try {
      keycloakService.init({
        config: keycloakConfig,
        initOptions: {
          onLoad: 'login-required',
          checkLoginIframe: false
        },
        enableBearerInterceptor: true,
        bearerExcludedUrls: ['.*']
      }).then(() => {
        app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Keycloak init failed', error);
    }
  }
}
```

**below, several links I have already visited**

[keycloak-angular github examples](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/tree/master/examples/webapp)
[A topic that raises a similar error with version 4.0.0 of the keycloak-service](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/11)

Comment: bearerExcludedUrls is for HttpClient to exclude Access Token transfer. Check Auth guard in `keycloak-service` documentation.

Comment: If I want an unlogged person to access a public page (e. g.'/public/cities') without redirecting to the keycloak login page, should I use'bearerExcludedUrIs'? If so, what should I wear? If not, how to proceed? 
I have already implemented and used the keycloak service guard. The latter checks that the user is well connected, and checks his roles before accessing a url.

Comment: I'm struggling with the very same issue. I tried to use the initializer Function, which allows to define a bearerExcludedUrls too. Not working either for me...

Answer (score 2):

For bearerExcludedUrls below code worked for me:

```
await keycloak.init({
  config: {
    url: 'url',
    realm: 'realm',
    clientId: 'clientId'
  },
  initOptions: {
    onLoad: 'check-sso',
    checkLoginIframe: false
  },
  bearerExcludedUrls: [
    'main$'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting with keycloak for two weeks now and I believe that I had simmilar problem. What I've tried is to comment keycloak init options "onLoad: 'login-required'".
After that I only have to login when I try to enter url which is protected by AuthGuard. For me "bearerExcludedUrls" didn't worked if 'login-required' is not commented out.

Comment: Use `onLoad: check-sso`  instead of `login-required`

Answer (score 0):

use check-sso in the initOptions rather than login-required

initOptions: {
onLoad :  'check-sso',
//onLoad :  'login-required',
flow : 'standard'
},

you you can call keycloakService.login(); when needed if you dont want to use it authguard.